# PHP header function does not work in several PHP versions and platforms

Tags: php

I have a stupid PHP script like this:

```
<?php
ob_start();
header("Status: 403 Forbidden");
echo "teste\n";
ob_end_flush();
```

The header is not sent. I have tried many workarounds, many OS platforms (Maverich, Ubuntu, Windows 7) and many PHP versions. And Also All  suggestions made here in stack overflow like verifying if there is no output before the header statement, checking whether there is any white character in the script, removing the final ?> and finally trying many of the tips to modify php.ini. I really tried hard to solve this problem without posting a question here.

Please, help em.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Please post it.

Comment: @eluong He said, the header is not sent.

Comment: @SecondRikudo The error message for header not sent usually gives you a line number and a description.

Comment: Umm, not really. In this case the header does probably get sent, but is not persed by the browser (because the header syntax makes no sense).

Comment: @SecondRikudo Good point on the syntax.

Comment: No error message, The header just is not sent.

Comment: Definitly the header is not sent because I already tested with if (!headers_sent())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not the correct header syntax.

The header text should be:

```
HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
```

Comment: I've managed to do what OP wanted by using [http_response_code](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php) - could be offered as an alternative?

Comment: `Status:` is actually well established for F/CGI and mod_php SAPIs. And PHP actually [transforms it if needed](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.cgi.rfc2616-headers). Not very likely OP runs it as NPH-CGI.

Comment: @hd. Could be. Worth noting that `http_response_code` is 5.4 and above.

Comment: @mario You're better off adhering to HTTP, rather than some dodgy API that you may or may not use.

Comment: http_response is not supported by our production PHP version.

Comment: Using Second Rikudo suggestion after modifications in the php.ini file the header is being sent now.

Comment: @user you should post an answer with what your solution was and accept it. Don't accept my answer if it didn't solve your problem.